# Minkowski vs. Lorentz metric

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, terminology, definition

Can anyone help me to understand the difference between Minkowski and Lorentzian metric?

They appear to me to be the very same: $$\langle x,y\rangle=-x_1\cdot y_1+x_2\cdot y_2+\ldots+x_n\cdot y_n.$$

EDIT:

For *Lorentzian* see this:

[image]

Comment: so is the Wiener process and Brownian motion.

Comment: @KurtG. And Random Walk ...

Comment: Physicists tend to use $x_0$, not $x_1$, for time.

Comment: The Minkowski metric is a particular case of a [Lorentzian metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold#Lorentzian_manifold). All GR metrics are Lorentzian.

Comment: You only showed one metric (Minkowski) so what do you mean by “they appear to me to be the very same”? The left and right sides of your equation are just different notations for the spacetime scalar product, not different metrics.

Comment: @Ghoster I wanted to know the difference between Lorentzian and Minkowski metric, please see my EDIT.

Comment: @Ghoster What is `GR` in your comment ?

Comment: Along the lines of @Ghoster's comment, Lorentzian usually refers to the "signature" (the signs of the diagonal entries) of which Minkowskian spacetime for Special Relativity (SR) is one special case of the more general spacetimes of General Relativity (GR). To refer to a vector space (as in your quoted passage [which should have a better reference]), Lorentzian and Minkowskian would mean the same thing.

Comment: *I wanted to know the difference between Lorentzian and Minkowski metric* For flat spaces like your book is talking about, they’re the same. You seem to be reading a book written more for mathematicians than physicists.

Comment: The [Schwarzschild metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric) is an example of a curved-spacetime metric in General Relativity (GR) which is Lorentzian but not Minkowskian (unless $M=0$, when it becomes the Minkowski metric written in spherical coordinates).

Answer (score 1):

On a general smooth $n$-dimensional manifold $M$, any metric with signature $(1,n-1)$ (or $(n-1,1)$ depending on the sign convention) is Lorentzian. The Minkowski metric is a Lorentzian metric specifically on $\mathbb R^n$.